# If $f_{xy}$ , $f_{yx}$ are continuous at $(x_{0},y_{0})$,then $f_{x},f_{y}$ are continuous at $(x_{0},y_{0})$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples, partial-derivative

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ ***The second edition***

Let $f$ be a function
 of two variables,let$(x_{0},y_{0})$ be a point and let $U$ be an open disk with center $(x_{0},y_{0})$.Assume that $f$ is defined on $U$ and its mixed partial derivatives $f_{xy}$ ,$f_{yx }$ exist on $U.$

If $f_{xy}$ , $f_{yx}$ are continuous at $(x_{0},y_{0})$,then $f_{x},f_{y}$ are continuous at $(x_{0},y_{0})$?

---

I think $\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x \partial y},\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial y \partial x} $ are contiunous at $(x_{0},y_{0})$ $\nRightarrow$  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y }$  are continuous at $(x_{0},y_{0})$. I want to find  a counterexample to support my
argument.

---

According to Daniel Fischer's best hints,I give my counterexample:

$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x})+y^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{y})\quad \text{as} \quad xy\ne0\quad; \\ 
\qquad \qquad  x^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x})\qquad\qquad\quad   \text{as} \quad x\ne0 \vee y=0\quad; \\ 
\qquad \qquad  y^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{y})\qquad\qquad\quad   \text{as} \quad x=0 \vee y\ne0\quad; \\ 
\quad\quad\quad\qquad0\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\text{as} \quad x=0 \vee y=0\quad.
\end{matrix}\right.\Longrightarrow $

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})& \text{as} \quad  x\ne0\\ 
 0                   &  \text{as} \quad  x=0
\end{matrix}\right.\quad$and$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 2y\sin(\frac{1}{y})-\cos(\frac{1}{y})& \text{as} \quad  y\ne0\\ 
 0                   &  \text{as} \quad  y=0
\end{matrix}\right.\quad$.$\Longrightarrow $ $\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x \partial y}(x,y)\equiv0\equiv\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial y \partial x}(x,y)!$ So  $f(x,y)$ is enough to satisfy my argument.

Anyone can give more simple counterexamples ?  Your reply will be higly appreciated!

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ doesn't exist for your $f$. Try something with $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} \equiv 0 \equiv \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer:Yes,the first function$f(x,y)$ that I gave is not correct.I edit it again! Thanks for your hints!